# Strongswan, how to configure ipsec site-to-site using psk?

Tags: networking, vpn, ipsec, strongswan

I'm setting up ipsec site-to-site VPN connection (with pre-shared key auth method). However I'm unsure of the correct values to put in ipsec.conf.

1. vpn server ip - xx.45.40.46
2. encryption algorithm - AES-256
3. Hash Algorithm - SHA
4. Authentication - PSK
5. DH Group - 2

When I run "ipsec start" and then "ipsec status aws-to-otherplace", it just says CONNECTING forever:

```
Security Associations (0 up, 1 connecting):
aws-to-otherplace[1]: CONNECTING, 192.168.65.3[%any]...xx.45.40.46[%any]
```

My ipsec.conf contains the following. How do I go about configuring this to match the inital specs listed above? Thanks

```
config setup
conn %default
    ikelifetime=60m
    keylife=20m
    rekeymargin=3m
    keyingtries=1
    keyexchange=ikev1
    authby=secret


conn aws-to-otherplace
    authby=secret
    left=%defaultroute
    leftid=xx.178.35.176
    leftsubnet=10.10.27.1/24
    right=xx.45.40.46
    rightsubnet=10.9.141.1/24
    ike=aes-sha1-modp1024
    esp=aes256-sha1
    keyingtries=0
    ikelifetime=1h
    lifetime=8h
    dpddelay=30
    dpdtimeout=120
    dpdaction=restart
    auto=start
```

ipsec.secrets

```
xx.178.35.176 xx.45.40.46 : PSK "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

start output: https://pastebin.com/raw/zTdJbWJd

Comment: And what does your strongSwan log file contain? It should tell you exactly where the handshake has failed. Perhaps your proposals or even timeouts don't match the other side (IKEv1 is _very_ picky), perhaps the leftid/rightid don't match what the other expects, perhaps strongSwan cannot find the PSK in `ipsec.secrets`...

Comment: i think the secrets file is correct. added that + output pastebin link to the orig post

Comment: Do you have access to the other side's logs? (Maybe it expects IKEv2, or has the entirely wrong IP address, or...)

Comment: this particular site-to-site is already connected (some company set it up for our office, now im moving it to AWS). the screenshot they send me says "IKEv1 IPSec" on it. its unlikely i can get logs from the other end, its ran by a terrible company in india

Comment: Ah, then I would again guess that you're connecting from the entirely wrong IP address. That is, I suspect the "other end" has a conn config with _your current office IP address_ as the peer address.

Comment: @grawity i think you're right. will have to disconnect the office i think then try again. thanks